# In VIsual Studio 2019, is there any way to view references of some method or property in ASPX files?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, webforms, visual-studio-2019

If I have a method or property defined in a class, then Find References and CodeLens only display references to that method or property in class files; they don't display references in ASPX files. Is there any way to get these to be displayed? I have to do a regular "find in files" and that finds a lot of false positives with similar names...

Answer (score 0):

It should pull through the references that are found in the code-behind files (i.e. aspx.cs) however, as far I'm aware it's set up to search files that have the same extension - so it won't look at aspx, just aspx.cs or cs.